# How do I move a second website onto my new hosting account?

Tags: web-hosting, migration

I have a website `example.gov.it` that I will call "old site", on a hosting that will expire soon. I bought another hosting to work on another website `example.edu.it` that I will call "site under construction". I would like to completely transfer the old site to new hosting, so I have two websites on the same hosting space.

I ask for instructions. At present, if the visitor types `example.edu.it` they are naturally directed to the site under construction. I would instead be directed to the old site (transferred to the new hosting). And I would like the site under construction not to be visible to the visitor and that it was for example on `example.edu.it/newwebsite`.

The two MySQL databases are in common. both are Linux hosting, the PHP version changes instead:

old site:

- PHP Version 5.3.29
- memory_limit: 128
- upload_max_filesize: 25

under construction site:

- PHP Version 5.4.16
- memory_limit: 512
- upload_max_filesize: 500

The old site is made with Drupal, while the one under construction with Joomla.

Comment: What the of hosting is your new hosting; dedicated server, VPS, managed server, shared hosting, or cloud hosting?  What tools do you have to modify the server: cpanel, root access, or something else?

Comment: both the old and the new hosting is shared hosting. I do not have root access. to manage hosting, I go to this address: https://managehosting.aruba.it/areautenti.asp

Comment: It is hard for us to know how to help you unless you can find out what software they are running at that link.    There are going to be different instructions depending what they are running.  If they are running something custom, the instructions would be unique to them.   The site is in Italian, which most of us here don't speak.  You'd be much better off contacting their customer support than asking here.

Comment: I do not need precise instructions depending on the software. I need generic instructions.

Comment: It is going to be different depending on the web server used.  Apache, Nginx, or IIS all have different configuration to do the same thing.   Most shared hosting environments use Apache, but they have a web application that allows clients to edit  their website configurations.  The most popular one is cPanel, but there are several dozen other ones.   None of them have you add additional sites quite the same way.   Some don't even allow you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to see if you have FTP access or the like. If you do on both sides, you can just transfer content that way. Otherwise, contact your hosting provider. They'll probably help you out

On the redirect, that requires dns record modifications. Usually, it's a cname that points to the new site, put in the old records. If you don't have dns record management, I'm afraid there is really no way to redirect. Check with your hosting provider to see if you do, unless you host elsewhere (I personally use cloudflare for my dns. I always recommend hosting your dns records separate from your website provider, makes hosting provider changes easier)